# SQL Server Mangement Studio - Generated database script not working

Tags: sql-server, database

I am having trobule trying to copy a database using sql server management studio.

The script which was generated using the wizard throws the following error when I try to run it to create the new database;

> Reference to database and/or server name in
>   'databasename'.dbo.sp_fulltext_database' is not supported in this
>   version of SQL server

This is despite generating the script using the correct version number and a couple of other ones to test.

I am following the steps in the following post

http://johanbenjaminsson.com/how-to-make-a-copy-of-an-umbraco-database/

Steps are not the exact same as the post is from a while back but the process is the same.

The line that seems to have the error is the following

```
EXEC [<databasename>].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database| @action = 'enable'
```

Struggling with this so any advice would be great.

Comment: Are you running it against Azure?

Comment: How do you mean? I am running the script from a command prompt. Apologies I do not have much experience with databases.

Comment: What happens when you remove "[<databasename>]."? (Given that your code is running against the right/new database.)